# Can't Access My Extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, string, overloading

Looking for a way to check if an string contains in another ignoring upper/lower case, I found [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring):

Works fine. Then, I tried put it to my `StringExtensions` namespace.

```
namespace StringExtensions
{

    public static class StringExtensionsClass
    {
        //... 

        public static bool Contains(this string target, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
        {
            return target.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

`using StringExtensions;`

...

```
if (".. a".Contains("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

but I get the following error:

> No overload for method 'Contains' takes '2' arguments

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my mistake:

for this works with `dynamic` type need use a `cast` to `string`. .`ToString()` method is not sufficient.

```
if (((string)result.body).Contains(foo, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Works fine now. 
Thanks again stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Right, because it's `dynamic` there's no guarantee that it doesn't have a method called `ToString` that returns something other than a string, so the result of any method call on a `dynamic` is always treated as `dynamic` by the compiler

Answer (score 26):

When you want to use your extension, add this using statement:

```
using StringExtensions;
```

Because of the way Extension methods are declared, visual studio won't find them by itself, and the regular `Contains` method takes one argument, hence your exception.

Comment: Yup -- Intellisense will only _appear_ to work because the method name already exists.